# Snowflake unable to display / interpret unicode '\u0089'

Tags: java, sql, unicode, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am trying to show Unicode character '\u0089' in the snowflake browser results, however it seems to be showing a default error value instead. I'm lost as to how to fix this issue

The data is being ingested from a source JSON doc which states the field to be

```
"Units": "\u0089"
```

[image]

As you can see, `"Units": "\u0089"` is not displaying correctly as ‰

One thing that is strange, is when removing the `char()` method. I've tried another code `137`, however when trying to covert back as a unicode it is incorrect

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `\u0089` is not the `PER MILLE SIGN(‰)`.  [`\u2030`](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf) is.  Your source JSON file is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm. thanks for that @MarkTolonen then what is \u0089?
if googled it is valid
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0089/index.htm
Do you know of any way to convert this to the correct one without changing the source system? (We are dealing with legacy software that we are ingesting data from)

Comment: U+0089 is a control code.  The *byte* 0x89 in Windows-1252 encoding is the per mille sign.  I'm not familiar with SQL syntax to convert from one encoding to another, but you would have to encode U+0089 as ISO-8859-1 encoding which has a 1:1 code point to byte translation, then decode with Windows-1252 encoding to get a per mille sign.

Comment: Thank you @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at Mark's comment - you can do this with a Java UDF:

```sql
create or replace function encode_decode_windows(s string)
returns string
language java
handler='MyClass.doit'
as
$$

    class MyClass {
        public static String doit(String s) throws Exception {
            return new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "Windows-1252");
        }
    }
$$;
```

Then to encode and decode to get a mile sign:

```sql
select encode_decode_windows('\u0089');

‰
```

Comment: On the subject of Unicode characters, too, Java UDFs in Snowflake use Java 11, [which uses Unicode database version 10.0](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html).